# Java Caching Stategy

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, grails, hazelcast

I have an e-Commerce-Software based on Grails Framework. Right now, we're using Hibernate SecondLevel Cache and Hazelcast (prior to Terracotta DSO) for distribution of our servers. This allows me to retreive objects directly (so I can call Objet.get(id) and I will get the object from Hibernate instead of an expensive database call.

I'm wondering how the "big" sites are doing this? Especially for category-pages with appended filters (such as price, ordering, brand) my method doesn't work anymore. What is the best-case strategy to avoid hitting the database all the time? Is it to have all in memory and order/sort/filter in Java instead of SQL queries?

Thanks for your feedback.

Update: Here's the ehcache.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ehcache name="Cache" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd">    
    <defaultCache maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000" timeToIdleSeconds="0"         
        timeToLiveSeconds="0">       
        <persistence strategy="distributed"/> 
        <elementValueComparator class="net.sf.ehcache.store.DefaultElementValueComparator"/>        
        <terracotta clustered="true">
            <nonstop enabled="true" />
        </terracotta>
    </defaultCache>  
    <terracottaConfig rejoin="true" url="tcURL:9510" />
    </ehcache>
```

and the hibernate configuration (taken from Grails):

```
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
```

Comment: How using `ehcache` as second level cache provider in `Hibernate`? Can read more [here](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/hibernate).

Comment: I was using Ehcache with Terracotta DSO, but the Querying touched the database every time, so my conclusion was it only works when you're receiving an object directly but not for querying (except for query cache, but it's not the right thing here since we have lots of transaction and the eviction is also expensive).

Comment: Can you show us ehcache config file `ehcache.xml` and hibernate property settings that you tried?

Comment: This [tutorial](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/04/hibernate-ehcache-configuration-tutorial/) can help you alot.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my post with the snippets you asked for. I'll check the tutorial, but as far as I've seen it's also about query caching?

Comment: yes tutorial includes `query caching` too.

Comment: Is it typo error in hibernate setting `cache.use_query_cache = false`? Should be `true` for query-cahce?

Comment: As mentioned, I don't want to use the query cache since we have lots of Product objects. So every time somebody changes just a little attribute value, all product queries must be invalidated and this is very expensive, I think?